# Is there a simpler way to deal with repeating DIVs?

Tags: html

I've been working on creating a series of about 100 or more flashcards that designed to look like index cards. In order to get the look of the blue horizontal lines for each card I have a block of about 20 repeating identical DIVs for each card. Since it's identical code for each card, is there a way to call the code with a function instead of repeating it over and over again? I'm pretty new to coding.

I'm open to any suggestion on how to improve this approach.

```
 <p> <li id="10" class="hideable"><div     class="tile flipX">
    <div class="front"><div id="paper">

<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
 <div class="margin"></div>  



<div id="content">
<p class="TOF"> </p>
    </div></div></div>

<div class="back"><div id="paper">

<p>
</p>

     </div></div></li>
```

Comment: Hey, you forgot to attach your code ;). Scratch that - it was the formatting that was hiding it. I've edited it so it appears but it might take time to be reviewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do this is if you were to use either PHP or ASP (or indeed Javascript as pointed out in the comments below). Here's an example of how you would achieve the result you're after using PHP:

## Basic example

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My example page</h1>
        <h2>my cards</h2>
        <?php
            for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
                echo '<div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This would result in the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My example page</h1>
        <h2>my cards</h2>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">.<div class="blueline"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the div's that you want are repeated 10 times thanks to the `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)` loop.

## Further example

You can do some "clever" things with PHP/ASP such as the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My example page</h1>
        <h2>my cards</h2>
        <?php
            for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
                echo '<div class="line">' . $i . '<div class="blueline"></div></div>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is effectively outputting the counter's (`$i`) value every iteration of the loop. This would be rendered by the browser as:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My example page</h1>
        <h2>my cards</h2>
        <div class="line">0<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">1<div class="blueline"></div></div>
        <div class="line">2<div class="blueline"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use that to your advantage for styling, id's, names, data, or whatever you like.

### Note

I've not included an example for Javascript as, if your users were to browse your website with Javascript turned off (which isn't as rare as you think) it could break the functionality of your site. Besides, PHP/ASP have several advantages such as integrating a database to your website and connecting it with facebook and other services.

Comment: Not the only way. You could use JavaScript to write the HTML on page load.

Comment: Agreed, but if someone has javascript turned off?

Comment: Pretty rare in practice, but yes, that would be a limitation. I mean in theory you could encounter a browser that didn't support the DIV tag given it wasn't part of HTML till version 5.

Another option is to use CSS pseudo elements to reduce the amount of HTML you have to write.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse not as rare as you think. I quite often run with javascript off. Even if the percentages are 5% off and 95% on, I'd still recommend using a server side scripting language as that's 5% of your users cannot use it due to their choice to have JS turned off

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse updated my answer to say it's not the only way but my recommendations on why not to use JS are at the bottom

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  I will try working with PHP and go from there.   Much appreciated.  I edited my original question to include the full code.  As you can imagine it gets pretty annoying to repeat those DIVs over and over again.

Comment: @K.McH cool. I'd have a look at the JS option too and see how you get on. I'd recommend going the PHP route as it's powerful and opens up a door to more possibilities but at the end of the day it's up to you! If you feel my answer is the one you were looking for, feel free to mark it as correct by clicking the tick beside the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this

```
<div id="paper"></div>

<script>
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
    var para = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode(".");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("paper");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
</script>
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbPBoj)

or you can try this instead

```
<div id="paper"></div>
<script>
  var tag = "<div class='line'>1<div class='blueline'></div></div>";
  var el = document.getElementById("paper");
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
    el.innerHTML += tag;
  }
</script>
```

please research further, I think I saw somewhere that `innerHTML` associated with security flaws.

Comment: +1 for the JS solution although my concerns with that still stand. That being said the OP might have an easier time learning JS.